# Datastructure to store bidirectional relationship

Tags: data-structures

I have googled and couldnt find any DS to store and read bi directional data in O(1) time. E.g. books and authors. With the name of book, authors has to be found. With the name of author, books has to be found.

How in DB, these relations like Join tables are stored?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is a combination of the following:

- A hash map of the first element to the second element (or a list of them)
- A hash map of the second element to the first element (or a list of them)

[Hash maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) give expected O(1) lookup.

I don't believe databases typically use hash maps though, more typically [b-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) as far as I know (giving O(log n) performance).

Comment: Thanks. I will check on b tree

Comment: I believe Teradata and SQL Server in-memory tables use hash indexes, FWIW.

Comment: The problem of Hash-table is: it use N space of memory (size of the hash value); Storing a large database index base on hash values only would either require huge data disks, or relocating data when collision happens too often. RB-tree or b-tree may improve that.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Dukeling's answer, I believe Google has an implementation called HashBiMap: [http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBiMap.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20160110232509/http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBiMap.html)