# smart way to save team members

Tags: java, list, architecture

I would like to have a list of teams with team members. 
(I am writing the example code in java, but the solution doesn't have to use java.) 
Like this:

```java
class Member {
    
}

class Team {
    ArrayList<Member> members;
}

ArrayList<Team> teams;
```

If I would like to access all the team members of one team, that would be pretty straight forward.
 **But what if I would like to see which team a member is part of?** 
 I don't want to loop over all teams team members every time.

I could save every member's team inside the member's class, but isn't that kind of dumb?

Comment: It might not be dumb. You could also create an associative array which maps members to their team.

Comment: what if a member is member of several teams?  there's no problem with iterating when searching, or just use streamss.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Datastructure to store bidirectional relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23323811/datastructure-to-store-bidirectional-relationship)

Comment: I think it would be better to have team variable inside `Member` than to use a `HashMap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a bidirectional association. You will need extra methods to make sure the data stays consistent. In the example I solved this problem by adding a `newMember` method to `Team`, but it could also be solved by adding setters that will set the team and update the member list at the same time.

```
class Member {
    final Team team;

    Member(Team team) {
        this.team = team;
    }
}

class Team {
    ArrayList<Member> members;

    public Member newMember() {
        Member member = new Members(this);
        members.add(member);
        return member;
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah I was worrying because i thought that every member would store a complete copy of the team and not a refrence to it as is usual in java... Thanks!

Comment: Yes it's usually not a problem. Just have to be careful when you generate code for methods like `equals` and `hashCode`. Then you need to ignore the attribute at one side of the relationship.

Answer (score -1):

Just use an Array of type String and a for loop to print out all teams and team members.

```
String[][] teams = new String[2][4];//[numer of team][max. number of memebers per team + one]
    
    teams[0][0] = "team1";
    teams[0][1] = "team1Member1";
    teams[0][2] = "team1Member2";
    teams[0][3] = "team1Member3";

    teams[1][0] = "team2";
    teams[1][1] = "team2Member1";
    teams[1][2] = "team2Member2";
    teams[1][3] = "team2Member3";

    //get all members of all teams



    for(int i = 0; i < teams.length; i++){
        System.out.println("team: " + teams[i][0]);
        for(int j = 1; j < teams[0].length; j++){
        System.out.println("\t" + teams[i][j]);
        }
    }
```